# AWS EC2 CloudWatch metrics interpretation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

How should I interpret the AWS EC2 CloudWatch NetworkIn and NetworkOut metrics?

What does the `Statistic: Average` in the chart refer to?

[image: CloudWatch]

Answer (score 3):

[The docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/cloudwatch_concepts.html#Units) state that "the units for the Amazon EC2 NetworkIn metric are Bytes because NetworkIn tracks the number of bytes that an instance receives on all network interfaces”.

When viewing the chart below, `Network In (Bytes)`, with `Statistic: Average` and a `Period: 5 Minutes` (note that the time window is zoomed in to around five hours, not one week), it is not immediately obvious how the average is calculated.
[image: NetworkIn Average]

Instance i-aaaa1111 (orange) at 15.29: **2664263.8**

If I change Statistic to “Sum”, I get this:
[image: NetworkIn Sum]

The same instance (i-aaaa1111), now at 15.31: **13321319**

It turns out **13321319**/5 = **2664263.8**, suggesting that incoming network traffic during those five minutes was, on average, 2664263.8 Bytes/minute.

=> 2664263.8/60 ≈ 44404.4 Bytes/second

=> 4404.39/1024 ≈ 43.3KB/s

=> 43.3*8 ≈ 350Kbps

I tested this by repeatedly copying a large file from one instance to another, transferring at an average speed of 30.1MB/s. The CloudWatch metric was 1916943925 Bytes (Average) => around 30.5MB/s

Comment: Have you tried using Sum instead of Avg? A while ago I did some verification comparing NetworkIn and ifconfig numbers and they are aligned: http://apps.axibase.com/chartlab/99e14b46

Comment: @SergeiRodionov if you read the whole post you'll see that I do :-)

Comment: Good point, I'm not sure why it's not adding up in your case. Can you confirm that bytes have been indeed incremented in ifconfig.

Answer (score 1):

The metric, "Network In (Bytes)", refers to bytes/minute.

It appears in my case that the average is computed over the period specified.  In other words: for '15 Minutes', it divides the sum of bytes for the 15-minute period by 15, for '5 Minutes', it divides the sum for the 5-minute period by 5.

Here is why I believe this: I used this chart to debug an upload where rsync was reporting ~710kB/sec (~727,000 bytes / sec) when I expected a faster upload.  After selecting lots of different sum values in the EC2 plot, I determined that the sums were correct numbers of bytes for the period specified (selecting a 15 minute period tripled the sum compared to a 5 minute period).  Then viewing the average and selecting different periods shows that I get the same value of ~45,000,000 when I select a period of "5 Minutes", "15 Minutes", or "1 Hour".

45,000,000 (bytes/???) / 730,000 (bytes/sec) is approximately 60, so ??? is a minute (60 seconds).  In fact, ~45,000,000 / 1024 / 60 = ~730 kB/sec and this is within 3% of what rsync was reporting.

Incidentally, my 'bug' was user error - I had failed to pass the '-z' option to rsync and therefore was not getting the compression boost I expected.

Comment: Once I knew the answer, then it was easy to find better source information, such as the answer at https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=56659 indicating that it is bytes/minute unless you select sum